# Removing HDMI cable causes a crash requiring a power down reset

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm dealing with a problem in my notebook that I need help resolving.

A few days ago I decided to update my Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 and now whenever I remove the HDMI cable it causes a freeze requiring a power down reset. This problem has not occurred with Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a Notebook Dell Latitude 7490, Graphics Coprocessor: ‎Intel UHD Graphics 620.

I will describe below some of the behaviours I have noted and also some things I have already tried.

If I boot the notebook with the HDMI cable connected (it doesn't matter if the second monitor is turned on or off) using Wayland on kernel 6.2.7-060207-generic with Secure Boot disabled everything works just fine. In that situation, if I remove the HDMI cable (it doesn't matter if the second monitor is turned on or off) after a while (it varies from 4 seconds to 120 seconds), a blink happens on the notebook screen and it stops working, requiring a hard reset.

Sometimes the screen just freeze and sometimes it goes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPXJT.jpg).

If I boot the notebook with the HDMI cable unconnected on kernel 6.2.7-060207-generic (I have also tried older kernel versions 5.0.0, 5.4.0, 5.11.0 and 5.15.0) with Secure Boot disabled the notebook freezes sometimes before even I finish typing my password. The only way I found to work without HDMI cable is to boot with the kernel on recovery mode. But, if I am using recovery mode kernels my second screen is not recognized.

So, right now, this is how I found it to work with my notebook. (i) If I don’t have a second monitor, I have to use the kernel on recovery mode. (ii) If I want to use the second monitor, I cannot unplug the HDMI cable or the notebook will crash.

Any idea on how to address this?

Comment: You may want to try a supported kernel. A 5.19 or 6.1 series.

Comment: Thank you @David for your suggestion. I tried that out, but couldn't get it to work. I have tried on kernels 5.19.17 and 6.1.21.

Looking at ```/var/log/syslog```, I noted the error ```meta_display_get_monitor_in_fullscreen: assertion 'monitor >= 0 && monitor < n_logical_monitors' failed``` right after removing the HDMI cable and I will investigate some more on that.